# Create a Webpack entry without a filename

Tags: webpack

I have a variable number of files that export a React Component:

e.g.

```
import React from 'react';
export default () => <h1>Hello World</h1>;
```

I would like to dynamically create a Webpack entry for each file, that imports the file.

e.g.

```
import React from 'react';
import React from 'react-dom';
import Component from '%with-file-name-inserted-here%';
ReactDOM.render(<Component/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

How can I dynamically create a Webpack entry from a code string (I'm happy to use the plugin API)?